# How to disable a pep8 error in a specific file?

Tags: python, pep8

I tried with

```
#:PEP8 -E223
```

or

```
# pep8: disable=E223
```

I thought the second would work but doesn't seems to work.

Do you have an idea how I can handle this ?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't.
You can disable errors or warnings user wide, or per project. See [the documentation](http://pep8.readthedocs.org/en/latest/intro.html#configuration).

Instead, you can use the `# noqa` comment at the end of a line, to skip that particular line (see [patch 136](https://github.com/jcrocholl/pep8/pull/136)). Of course, that would skip all PEP8 errors.

The main author argues against [source file noise](https://github.com/jcrocholl/pep8/pull/27#issuecomment-11509431), so they suggested `# pep8` comments don't get included.

---

Note that there is also `nopep8`, which is the equivalent. `noqa` (which stands for [No Quality Assurance](https://github.com/PyCQA/pycodestyle/issues/476) was added [in version 1.4.1](https://github.com/PyCQA/pycodestyle/blob/08f48912d88e4c8104813cc2834e634841f0301c/CHANGES.txt#L393) to support people [running `pyflakes` next to `pep8`](https://github.com/PyCQA/pycodestyle/issues/149).

Comment: Thanks. But in my case, I don't want to skip a specific line :-(
To my mind, it is less poluting to add something like "# pep8: disable E221" at the begining of the file than specify each line to ignore. But it is my point !
Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 50):

Try putting `# nopep8` at the end of the line (after two spaces). So if the line of code is:

```
h=1+2+3+4+5+6+func( "hello","world")
```

then to ignore the copious pep8 errors for that line it becomes:

```
h=1+2+3+4+5+6+func( "hello","world")  # nopep8
```

Comment: It seems that this can be combined with a specific error type, e.g. `# nopep8: E501`

Comment: the irony of making a line longer to say you want it ignored for length

Answer (score 31):

Let me add something that was probably introduced after all the previous answers were posted.

If you use Flake8, you can ignore a specific violation raised in a specific line, by adding

```
# noqa: F401
```

at the end of the line, where `F401` here is an example of an error code. For a list of all violations code, see http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/3.5.0/user/error-codes.html and https://pycodestyle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#error-codes

You can also ignore all violations in an entire file by adding

```
# flake8: noqa
```

anywhere in the file.

Reference: http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/3.5.0/user/violations.html

Comment: Thank you sir, this does not answer the precise question but it does come up in a search for what you answered and that is helpful :) Disabling at a line is what I and others who will arrive here needed!

Answer (score 28):

You can use `--ignore` flag to disable the error you mentioned above

```
pep8 --ignore=E223 file_name.py
```

for multiple errors

```
pep8 --ignore=E223,E501 file_name.py
```

For more in depth knowledge of other flags you can scan through http://pep8.readthedocs.org/en/latest/intro.html

Comment: This doesn't answer the question (while it may be useful).

Answer (score 3):

You can do that using Flake8 together with https://github.com/jayvdb/flake8-putty

Comment: `flake8-putty` is definitely the best approach overall - cause it allows a much more granular control which things to disable for what files.

Comment: Unfortunately not compatible with flake8 version 3 and no plans to fix: https://github.com/jayvdb/flake8-putty/issues/14

Answer (score 1):

If you use Flake8 3.7.0+, you can ignore specific warnings for entire files using the [`--per-file-ignores`](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/options.html?highlight=per-file-ignores#cmdoption-flake8-per-file-ignores) option.

Command-line usage:

```
flake8 --per-file-ignores='project/__init__.py:F401,F403 setup.py:E121'
```

This can also be specified in a [config file](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/configuration.html):

```
[flake8]
per-file-ignores =
    __init__.py: F401,F403
    setup.py: E121
    other/*: W9
```

Comment: this answers another question but not OP's

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with, for example, your setup configuration file (`setup.cfg`):

```py
[tool:pytest]
pep8ignore =
    *.py E501 W503
    api.py E402                <=============== HERE
    doc/* ALL
pep8maxlinelength = 120
flakes-ignore =
    UnusedImport
filterwarnings =
  ignore::DeprecationWarning
```

Answer (score -1):

In the IDE of [LiClipse](https://www.liclipse.com/), you can add `--ignore=E501` in Code Analysis from Preference.

If anyone uses Eclipse like IDE, this is the convenient way to do it.

[image]